# Is it possible to schedule a script to run automatically in RStudio server?

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I was just wondering if it is possible to schedule a script to run automatically (e.g. every Monday) on RStudio server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have shell and CRON access on the server you can accomplish this via a crontab entry like this:

```
0 7 * * mon   /usr/bin/Rscript $HOME/scriptname.R >> $HOME/tmp/out 2>&1
```

This is lightly modified from one I use. This example would run your script at 7am each Monday.